# I am having trouble in computing a simple arithmetic using python

Tags: python, math, typeerror

I want to compute this simple arithmetic problem:
`6/2(1+2)`

But it keeps giving me this error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` no matter what method I try to use. What should I do?

Comment: Add a * (multiply) = [6/2*(1+2)]. And square brackets are list in Python

Comment: you need to use `*` operator to multiply.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `*` character between 2 and parenthesis.
The way you wrote is, is like you'd call a function i.e `func()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use * operator to multiply.

Try this:

```
(6/2*(1+2))
```